# Radio form value not showing up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I am a still a newbie so sorry for any mistakes. I have searched a lot and couldn't solve my problem. I dynamically created this radio input:

```
var radio_input = document.createElement('input');
radio_input.type = "radio";
radio_input.name = "test_input"
radio_input.value = "teeest";
radio_input.appendChild(my_form);
```

However I can't get the input value to show up. I get something similar to this:
[image: test_input] (but one instead of 3)

I want to have "test" written in the left side of the input... Can someone help me?

Comment: An input of type radio doesnt have a place for text itself, you have to attach a label element to show text next to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As  @RobertoLinare said in his comment,  you can create a div and append the label:

```js
var radio_input = document.createElement('input');
var label = document.createElement('label');
var div = document.createElement('div');

radio_input.type = "radio";
radio_input.name = "test_input"
radio_input.value = "teeest";

label.innerHTML = "Label";
document.getElementById("my_form").appendChild(div);
div.appendChild(label);
div.appendChild(radio_input);
```

```html
<form id="my_form">

</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Html :

```
<form id="my_form"></form>
```

JS :

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("my_form");

// Clear previous contents of the container
while (myForm.hasChildNodes()) {
    myForm.removeChild(myForm.lastChild);
}

var radio_input = document.createElement("input");
radio_input.type = "radio";
radio_input.name = "test_input";
radio_input.value = "teeest";

var label = document.createElement('label');
label.innerHTML = "Label Title ";

myForm.appendChild(radio_input); 
myForm.appendChild(label);
```

Comment: This is no different from his code, except it uses jQuery.